# Use custom puppet functions in Vagrant

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I'm trying out custom functions in puppet for the first time to write some simple helper functions for my manifests.  I put the code in `{my_module}/lib/parser/functions/myhelper.rb`, but if I understand correctly you need to enable `pluginsync` and it doesn't look like vagrant supports that (I tried passing `--pluginsync` to puppet.options, but it didn't work).

Is there any way to use custom functions in Vagrant?

EDIT: My vagrant box is using puppet 2.7.18

Answer (score 1):

Custom functions should "just" work under vagrant, no need to enable any pluginsync,

I think your problem is the function path, it should be:

```
{my_module}/lib/puppet/parser/functions/myhelper.rb
```